# ASP.NET Identity not authorizing properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

I am attempting to create a simple Login route and this code works fine for logging in and sending the cookie to the browser:

```
[Route("Login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(UserBindingModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {              
        var user = await UserManager.FindUserAsync(model.username, model.password);

        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, true);
            return Ok();
        }              
    }

    return BadRequest();
}
```

Here is the SignInAsync method that's being called:

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
    Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

Here is my IdentityConfig:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new TestUserStore());

        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = false,
        };
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }

        return manager;
    }

    public async Task<ApplicationUser> FindUserAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        var userStore = new TestUserStore();
        ApplicationUser user = await userStore.FindByNameAsync(username, password);
        return await Task.FromResult(user);
    }
}
```

Despite this sending the cookie to the browser correctly and the authentication portion working, whenever I call another api controller I keep getting that the request is unauthorized. I am not extremely familiar with the identity framework so I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Can you include your Startup Auth code?

Comment: "api method", you mean ApiController?

Comment: @john The identityconfig code is my startup.auth code

Comment: @KimHoang Yes, I meant the api controller. Any one of those that needs authorization is not being called.

Comment: @John Sorry for the confusion. I just added the startup.auth code

Comment: I think you are using System.Web.Http.Authorize attribute on your api controller. You need to acquite bearer access token. Then include it as Authorization header of your api request. Then you can access your API.

Comment: I think you need something a bit like this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/02/18/evolving-asp-net-appscookie-authentication/
At the moment, I can't see that your application would know to look for the cookie. I could be mistaken though.

Comment: are you sending the token in the request header?

Comment: @KimHoang I don't understand. Why do I need a token as well with cookie-based authentication? Shouldn't the cookie being sent to the server be enough to authorize the user?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi No, I have not added any token stuff. I will have to look that up. I was under the impression that all you need with cookie-based authentication is the cookie. I suppose that cookie is not able to be used for authorization.

Comment: Yeah guys from what I'm seeing I don't need to send any tokens since I'm using cookie-based authentication.. I think.

Comment: I'm think the problem has something to do with it not signing in properly.. I'm still stumped.

Comment: Where are you getting the error, and what specific error are you getting?  Have you examined the cookie on the hard drive to ensure it has the expected data?  Do you see it being included in the calls to the api, via Fiddler or another network sniffing tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were 2 errors with my original code

1.) The Default Authentication Types were not consistent. They should have all been ApplicationCookie

2.) In the Web API config, I had to comment out the following lines:

```
  config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
  config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

This was setting the authentication type to "Bearer", which was inconsistent with my Application Cookie Authentication approach and thus causing the problems I encountered.